# Simulating C# overflow in NodeJS

Tags: c#, .net, node.js

I am trying to translate C# code to nodejs and I've hit a wall. One of the functions in C# uses a bytes to generate 3 numbers using BitConverter.toInt64 like so:

```
    var hashText = //Generates Hash from an input here using ComputeHash

    var hashCodeStart = BitConverter.ToInt64(hashText, 0);  
    var hashCodeMedium = BitConverter.ToInt64(hashText, 8);
    var hashCodeEnd = BitConverter.ToInt64(hashText, 24);


 //Does other stuff with the three pieces here
```

As an example, if I use the array:

```
var hash = new Byte[] {0xAA, 0x9B, 0x50, 0xA7, 0x56, 0x8D, 0x2A, 0x99, 0x87, 0xA7, 0x24, 0x10, 0xF8,0x1E, 0xC3, 0xA2, 0xF9, 0x57, 0x1A, 0x2D, 0x69, 0x89, 0x83, 0x91, 0x2D, 0xFA, 0xA5, 0x4A, 0x4E, 0xA2, 0x81, 0x25};
```

Then the values for start, middle, and end are:

```
Start : -7409954833570948182

Middle: -6718492168335087737

End : 2702619708542548525
```

But using NodeJS with the [biguinut-format package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/biguint-format) I get the following numbers (code below):

```
start : 12293508287479753369

middle : 9774821171531793314

end : 17966858020764353425
```

with the following NodeJS

```
    var hexed = "aa9b50a7568d2a9987a72410f81ec3a2f9571a2d698983912dfaa54a4ea28125"
    var format = require('biguint-format')

    console.log(hexed.toUpperCase().slice(0, 16))
    console.log("Start is " + format(hexed.toUpperCase().slice(0, 16), 'dec'))

    console.log(hexed.toUpperCase().slice(16, 32))
    console.log("Middle is " + format(hexed.toUpperCase().slice(16, 32), 'dec'))

    console.log(hexed.toUpperCase().slice(32, 48))
    console.log("End is " + format(hexed.toUpperCase().slice(32, 48), 'dec'))
```

I understand that the numbers for C# are coming out negative because of some overflow, however the problem is that the overflow seems to happen before the maximum that can be stored by int64.

Is there anyway for me to find out which number this is, or any other way for me to emulate the C# code?

Comment: you probably want to use a UInt64

Comment: I can't alter C# code in any way. I need my NodeJS to give the same output as this C# code.

Comment: even with overflow I cannot see how these two numbers are related - 7409954833570948182  12293508287479753369, overflow for that number should be -6153235786229798247

Comment: That's precisely my question. Its not overflowing in the expected manner and I can't understand why, or how I can emulate this functionality in NodeJS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your using a string instead of a buffer and splitting the bites so you have an array of 16 digits instead of 8 hex values I don't know if that will make a difference or if its being converted wrong try using the documented way

```
var buffer1 = new Buffer([0xAA, 0x9B, 0x50, 0xA7, 0x56, 0x8D, 0x2A, 0x99, 0x87]);
format(buffer1, 'dec', {format:'LE'})
```

you potentially will still get an uint so you will need to convert it to a signed int afterwards

As @argaz mentions BitConverter is usually little endian, thus the need for the LE flag.

Comment: According to the documentation strings are allowed, however I did omit the {format : 'LE"} which solved the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: An endianess issue: `BitConverter` is usually little endian, thus the need for the `LE` flag.